Parquet encryption using Spark
I am trying to encrypt parquet files using envelope encryption. I created RSA keys in Oracle Cloud Infrastructure (OCI) KMS. I am using spark parquet to encrypt/decrypt files but I am running into following error while decrypting:
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o190.parquet.
    : org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 3) (10.244.135.196 executor 4): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 4 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: 
    The executor with id 4 exited with exit code 50(Uncaught exception).
    
    
    
    The API gave the following container statuses:
    
    
        container name: spark-kubernetes-executor
        container image: iad.ocir.io/axoxdievda5j/dataflow-spark-livy-delta:V3-3.2.1.188.4fc0b0026ee
        container state: terminated
        container started at: 2024-05-30T18:46:23Z
        container finished at: 2024-05-30T18:47:52Z
         exit code: 50
         termination reason: Error
    Driver stacktrace:
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:2454)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2(DAGScheduler.scala:2403)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:2402)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:2402)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1(DAGScheduler.scala:1160)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:1160)
        at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:407)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:1160)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2642)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2584)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2573)
        at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:938)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2238)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2259)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2278)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2303)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$collect$1(RDD.scala:1030)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:414)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:1029)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SchemaMergeUtils$.mergeSchemasInParallel(SchemaMergeUtils.scala:70)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetFileFormat$.mergeSchemasInParallel(ParquetFileFormat.scala:531)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetUtils$.inferSchema(ParquetUtils.scala:107)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetFileFormat.inferSchema(ParquetFileFormat.scala:163)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.$anonfun$getOrInferFileFormatSchema$11(DataSource.scala:210)
        at scala.Option.orElse(Option.scala:447)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.getOrInferFileFormatSchema(DataSource.scala:207)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:411)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:274)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.$anonfun$load$3(DataFrameReader.scala:245)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:245)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.parquet(DataFrameReader.scala:596)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
        at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
        at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
        at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
        at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
        at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)

Followed the following spark document for KMSClient: https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.2.1/sql-data-sources-parquet.html#kms-client
Here is my py implementation for decryption:
import logging
from pathlib import Path

from src.shared.global_enums import CommandLineArguments, PathConsts
from src.shared.helper_util import HelperUtils
from src.shared.spark_join_helper import SparkJoinUtils
from src.shared.spark_util import SparkUtils

LOGGER = logging.Logger

def run(job_args, spark):
    global display_record_df
    required_params = [CommandLineArguments.run_root.value, CommandLineArguments.target_root.value]
    required_args = HelperUtils.get_required_args(job_args, required_params)
   
    run_root_path = HelperUtils.validate_path(required_args[CommandLineArguments.run_root.value])
    target_root_path = HelperUtils.get_target_path(job_args)
    
    source_path = HelperUtils.validate_path(
        run_root_path +
        str(Path(PathConsts.source_path.value,
                 PathConsts.source_sub_dir_path.value))
    )

    target_path = HelperUtils.validate_path(
        target_root_path +
        str(Path(PathConsts.target_path.value,
                 PathConsts.tar_sub_dir_path.value))
    )

    sc = spark.sparkContext
    sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set('parquet.encryption.kms.client.class', 'com.example.encrypt.ParquetEnvelopeDecryption')
    sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set('parquet.encryption.uniform.key', 'master_public1')
    sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set('parquet.encryption.complete.columns', 'true')
    sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set('parquet.crypto.factory.class',
                                      'org.apache.parquet.crypto.keytools.PropertiesDrivenCryptoFactory')
    sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set('parquet.encryption.double.wrapping', 'false')
    # sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set('parquet.encryption.key.material.store.internally', 'false') enable for key rotation
    sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set('parquet.encryption.plaintext.footer', 'false')
    sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set('log4j.logger.com.example.encrypt','DEBUG')

    print(f"source path: {source_path}")
    print(f"target path: {target_path}")

    print('Before read parquet')
    display_record_df = SparkUtils.read_parquet_data(source_path, spark)
    print('After read parquet')

    position1 = sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().get('position1')
    print(f'value for position is {position1}')
    columns = display_record_df.columns

    for column in columns:
        print(column)

    # output_df = format_output(display_record_df)
    SparkUtils.write_parquet_data(display_record_df, target_path)

This is the implementation of ParquetEnvelopeDecryption as KmsClient implementation:
package com.example.encrypt;

import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.KeyFactory;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.PrivateKey;
import java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException;
import java.security.spec.PKCS8EncodedKeySpec;
import java.util.Base64;
import java.util.HashMap;
import javax.crypto.BadPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException;
import javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException;

import com.oracle.bmc.auth.ResourcePrincipalAuthenticationDetailsProvider;
import com.oracle.bmc.keymanagement.KmsCryptoClient;
import com.oracle.bmc.keymanagement.model.DecryptDataDetails;
import com.oracle.bmc.keymanagement.requests.DecryptRequest;
import com.oracle.bmc.keymanagement.responses.DecryptResponse;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.parquet.crypto.KeyAccessDeniedException;
import org.apache.parquet.crypto.keytools.KmsClient;

public class ParquetEnvelopeDecryption implements KmsClient {
  public void initialize(Configuration configuration, String s, String s1, String s2) throws KeyAccessDeniedException {}

  public String wrapKey(byte[] bytes, String s) throws KeyAccessDeniedException {
    return "";
  }

  public byte[] unwrapKey(String wrappedKey, String masterKeyIdentifier) throws KeyAccessDeniedException {
    try {
      return decryptWithOaep(wrappedKey);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
  }

  public static byte[] decryptWithOaep(String cipherText) {
    ResourcePrincipalAuthenticationDetailsProvider resourcePrincipalAuthenticationDetailsProvider = ResourcePrincipalAuthenticationDetailsProvider.builder().build();

    KmsCryptoClient kmsCryptoClient = KmsCryptoClient.builder().build(resourcePrincipalAuthenticationDetailsProvider);

    DecryptDataDetails decryptDataDetails = DecryptDataDetails.builder()
            .ciphertext(cipherText)
            .keyId("<key_id>")
            .keyVersionId("<key_version_id>")
            .encryptionAlgorithm(DecryptDataDetails.EncryptionAlgorithm.RsaOaepSha1).build();

    DecryptRequest decryptRequest = DecryptRequest.builder().decryptDataDetails(decryptDataDetails).build();

    DecryptResponse decryptResponse = kmsCryptoClient.decrypt(decryptRequest);
    return decryptResponse.getDecryptedData().getPlaintext().getBytes();
  }
}

Spark is suppose to call ParquetEnvelopeDecryption class for decryption logic. I see Before read parquet in my logs and fails after with the above mentioned exception. This indicates either it is not able to call the class or there is a bug in the class implementation.
Any lead to overcome this will be helpful. Thanks in advance.
